# How can I quickly encode and then compress a short string containing numbers in c#

Tags: c#

I have strings that look like this:

```
000101456890
348324000433
888000033380
```

They are strings that are all the same length and they contain only numbers.

I would like to find a way to encode and then ompress (reduce the length) of the strings. The compression algoithm would need to just compress down to ASCII characters as these will be used as web page links.

So for example:

```
www.stackoverflow.com/000101456890  goes to www.stackoverflow.com/aJks
```

Is there some way I could do this, some method that would do the job of compressing quickly.

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't the easiest way to compress a string containing numbers to store it as a number and not a string?

Comment: @AntonyW - I added some things to the question. Hope this explains it better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do it *simply*, you could consider each as a `long` (plenty of room there), and hex-encode; that gives you:

```
60c1bfa
5119ba72b1
cec0ed3264
```

base-64 would be shorter, but you'd need to look at it as big-endian (note most .NET is little-endian) and ignore leading 0 bytes. That gives you:

```
Bgwb+g==
URm6crE=
zsDtMmQ=
```

For example:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        long x = 000101456890L, y = 348324000433L, z = 888000033380L;

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(x, 16));
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(y, 16));
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(y, 16));

        Console.WriteLine(Pack(x));
        Console.WriteLine(Pack(y));
        Console.WriteLine(Pack(z));

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt64("60c1bfa", 16).ToString().PadLeft(12, '0'));
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt64("5119ba72b1", 16).ToString().PadLeft(12, '0'));
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt64("cec0ed3264", 16).ToString().PadLeft(12, '0'));

        Console.WriteLine(Unpack("Bgwb+g==").ToString().PadLeft(12, '0'));
        Console.WriteLine(Unpack("URm6crE=").ToString().PadLeft(12, '0'));
        Console.WriteLine(Unpack("zsDtMmQ=").ToString().PadLeft(12, '0'));

    }
    static string Pack(long value)
    {
        ulong a = (ulong)value; // make shift easy
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>(8);
        while (a != 0)
        {
            bytes.Add((byte)a);
            a >>= 8;
        }
        bytes.Reverse();
        var chunk = bytes.ToArray();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(chunk);
    }
    static long Unpack(string value)
    {
        var chunk = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        ulong a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < chunk.Length; i++)
        {
            a <<= 8;
            a |= chunk[i];
        }
        return (long)a;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could encode with a key so as to make the links secure. What I have right now is that if a user knows one link they can see the next by just upping the number. I want to try and make that impossible by encoding.

Comment: @czhili do you work for citibank by any chance? The correct thing to do there is ***verify access to links***. You might also consider non-consecutive identifiers, but even then you should *still* validate access. Finally, sure; you could add some key-based scrambling - but you should *still* validate access.

Comment: @czhili comment: WTF. Longer explanation: if it matters that one person can up the number to get to a new 'link' then your doing links very wrong.

Comment: I'll give you another thing to think about. If i CANT increase the value by 1 to get a new valid link do you care if i use a **complicated** technique to get another valid link?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. I will adopt the technique above.

Comment: The urls returned by Pack() are not url-safe. They contain '/' chars.

Comment: What could be the BigInteger version of Pack/Unpack functions? I need to work with larger numbers. I've done Unpack(BigInteger value) but Pack part fails.

Comment: Is the value `long x = 000101456890L` in base 10?

Comment: @DavidG yes; `0x` as a prefix would denote hex, `0b` would denote binary, but just numbers: base 10

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure Base 64 is url safe since it has '/' in its index table (the pack function provided in the selected answer will yield non url-safe strings).

You can consider replacing the '/' symbol by something more url friendly or use another base. Base 62 will do it here, for instance.

Here is a generic code that translates back and forth from decimal to any numeral base <= 64 (it's probably faster then converting to bytes and then using Convert.ToBase64String()):

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Decode("101456890", 10));
    Console.WriteLine(Encode(101456890, 62));
    Console.WriteLine(Decode("6rhZS", 62));
    //Result:
    //101456890
    //6rhZS
    //101456890
}

public static long Decode(string str, int baze)
{
    long result = 0;
    int place = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i)
    {
        result += Value(str[str.Length - 1 - i]) * place;
        place *= baze;
    }

    return result;
}

public static string Encode(long val, int baze)
{
    var buffer = new char[64];
    int place = 0;
    long q = val;
    do
    {
        buffer[place++] = Symbol(q % baze);
        q = q / baze;
    }
    while (q > 0);

    Array.Reverse(buffer, 0, place);
    return new string(buffer, 0, place);
}

public static long Value(char c)
{
    if (c == '+') return 62;
    if (c == '/') return 63;
    if (c < '0') throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("c");
    if (c < ':') return c - '0';
    if (c < 'A') throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("c");
    if (c < '[') return c - 'A' + 10;
    if (c < 'a') throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("c");
    if (c < '{') return c - 'a' + 36;
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("c");
}

public static char Symbol(long i)
{
    if (i < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("i");
    if (i < 10) return (char)('0' + i);
    if (i < 36) return (char)('A' + i - 10);
    if (i < 62) return (char)('a' + i - 36);
    if (i == 62) return '+';
    if (i == 63) return '/';
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("i");
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can consider replacing the '/' symbol by something more url friendly.