# Why does INI file contain duplicate lines?

Tags: c#, ini

I'm trying to encrypt a whole INI file to make it unreadable. My code duplicates the same line. Below code that is run 3 times with the result inserted into an INI file:

> [c7DuuqP28h8=]
>
> nJvr1BlIML2vaJtyHa4jHw===X84CG/IurDg=
>
> nJvr1BlIML2vaJtyHa4jHw===X84CG/IurDg=
>
> nJvr1BlIML2vaJtyHa4jHw===X84CG/IurDg=

Here is my code:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
        string key, string val, string filePath);
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
             string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
        int size, string filePath);


    public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, string Value)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(passphrase))
        {
            Section = Encryption.EncryptString(Section, passphrase);
            Key = Encryption.EncryptString(Key, passphrase);
            Value = Encryption.EncryptString(Value, passphrase);
        }
        WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
    }
```

---

```
      //Calling the function
      ini.IniWriteValue("Login", "username", chkRememberUsername.Checked ? username.Text : "");
```

**UPDATE:**

It's beacuse of if Keyname or Value contains = sign then the line becomes a different thing than the original. So I need to eliminate = sign from both of Keyname & Value. I googled & found Pack & Unpack solution of [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) and used it in reverse to encode = signs.

[Encode strings as numeric chars only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356306/how-can-i-quickly-encode-and-then-compress-a-short-string-containing-numbers-in)

Comment: @Paolo I think, it is implied by the title "[what is the] INI file keyname length?". However, the OP should make that clear.

Comment: Ok got it... = signs at the end of the Keyname make a confussion. nJvr1BlIML2vaJtyHa4jHw===X84CG/IurDg= should be "nJvr1BlIML2vaJtyHa4jHw==" = "X84CG/IurDg="