# Encode and compress a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a client side app. Users can select a few widgets on the page and share their selection with friends by sending them the URL of the page. I'm planning on saving the user's widget selections via a query string. I'd like the URL to be as small as possible so that it's easier for people to share.

Now to my question. I have a string of characters (8) that I'd like to encode so that output of the encoding is *significantly* smaller. I realize that 8 characters isn't very big but it's got potential to get larger in the future.

```
//using hex encoding results in a saving of 1 character
(98765432).toString(16) //"5e30a78"

example.com?q=98765432 vs example.com?q=5e30a78
```

Ideally I'd like the new string to be 4 characters or less. What are my options for encoding a string that will be used in URLs?

---

I've looked at this question: [How can I quickly encode and then compress a short string containing numbers in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356306/how-can-i-quickly-encode-and-then-compress-a-short-string-containing-numbers-in) but the encoded string is still too long.

Comment: First of all: what are restrictions on these characters? Are they digits only? Generally if all characters are possible then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: I'd like to use [a-zA-Z0-9] for both my raw and encoded string. I'm open to changing this if that means I can generate a small URL. Downside to using less characters is that my raw string would grow from 8 to potentially 16 characters.

Comment: There's *very* little scope to compress that range of characters using characters valid in URLs (because those are the vast majority of characters which are allowed in URLs).

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. If both (the input and the output) have the same characters available but the output should be shorter, then you will have collisions (i.e. two or more source strings will map the same target string).

Comment: @FelixKling Yep, pure math. However if you drop the "should be shorter" assumption then you can figure out a compression function that will shorten most common cases. And it will yield unique results. At the cost of some cases being actually longer. Just like real compression algorithms work anyway.

Comment: I don't know much about encoding which is why I'm asking the question. I'm open to changing the raw input characters if that makes the output smaller.

Comment: @freakish: Yes, OP would then only need to tell us what those "most common cases" are.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean by "most common cases". As I've said, I'm open to changing the character restrictions for the raw / encoded string. Would this question be better if my raw file contained only numbers but was 16 characters long? The encoded output would be [a-zA-Z0-9].

Comment: @Jordan: You'll want to learn about [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). There's only so much information that can be encoded in a limited set of strings (limited in length and available characters). You cannot make it smaller than what you need.

Comment: @Jordan: You can encode all 16-digit numbers in alphanumeric strings of length 11. Not sure whether that buys you anything.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short tale about compression:

Let's say that you have an alphabet `A` and you have a set of words `W(A)` in alphabet `A`. Consider function

```
f: W(A) -> W(A)
```

which takes a word `w` and maps it into a word `f(w)` in the same alphabet.

Now it can be shown that if this function is invertible **and** there is a word `w1` such that

```
length(f(w1)) < length(w1)
```

(i.e. we've compressed the word) **then** there exists a word `w2` such that the opposite holds

```
length(f(w2)) > length(w2)
```

So this means that every compression method you've ever heard of is actually an illusion. For every method there is a file that will be *larger* after compression. It works because compression methods make assumptions about initial files. For example that these are words written in natural language. They are optimized for such cases and fail for other cases like whitenoise.

---

Back to your problem. If you wish to compress `[a-zA-Z0-9]` words onto itself **and** all cases are possible then you are doomed.

But there are at least two things you can think about:

1. Find most common `[a-zA-Z0-9]` words and map them onto small words. For example you found out that the case `example.com?q=98765432` is most common among your users. Then you will map it to `example.com?c=1` (note the parameter change). You will need a dictionary for such mappings. Of course for same rare cases you will end up with larger url, e.g. `example.com?q=abcd` will be mapped to `example.com?c=abcdefgh` unfortunately.
2. Restrict your input alphabet and enlarge your output alphabet. The bigger the difference, the bigger **real** compression is possible. Note that unfortunately there is a quite low upper limit for the alphabet used in URLs, namely 128 (ascii characters). For example if you have alphabet `A={1,2}` and `B={1,2,3,4,5,6}` then you can map `1~1, 2~2, 11~3, 12~4, 21~5, 22~6` which basically means that every word in `A` can be written in `B` in such a way that you reduce the size by half.